# Insert Object Reference Into Table

Tags: database-design, postgresql-9.6

I'm currently learning about object-relational databases and decided to whip up an example in PostgreSQL to test what I'm learning. Here is the example I wrote up for testing:

```
Create Type item_type As (name text, weight integer);

Create Type inventory_type As (item item_type, stock integer);

Create Table item Of item_type;

Create Table inventory Of inventory_type;

Insert Into item Values
('Block', 10),
('Ball', 2);

Insert Into inventory (item, stock)
Select item, 1 From item;
```

I then run `Update item Set weight = 8 Where name = 'Block';` and the value correctly updates in the item table,  but I don't see the changes in the inventory table. I'm guessing that's because the insert into inventory is creating copies of the rows and inserting them into the inventory table.

**Is there a way I can insert a reference to the object into the table?** If so, is there any documentation on how to work with said reference? I've read about OIDS and that I can add them to the table using the `WITH (OIDS)` but it seems like I could achieve the same thing with a `serial` attribute, but that doesn't strike me as very object-relational.